# How to Pass * as an argument to shell script?

Tags: shell

I am using a shell script to collect data from db, the using command is given below:

```
$sh /tmp/testdb.sh "select * from table1;"
```

the query is getting by shell script is like this:

```
select Desktop Documents Downloads Music Pictures Public Templates Videos from table1;
```

the * is here taking as all files present in that directory, so How can I overcome this issue , please help me.

Comment: Make use of single quotes instead of double: `sh /tmp/testdb.sh 'select * from table1;'`

Comment: The command you posted does not produce the result you report. The problem is in `/tmp/testdb.sh`, almost certainly missing quotes. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable

Comment: I tried with single quote(') also but no luck, given below is the piece of shell script what I am usng:
===============
#! /bin/bash

params=$1
echo $params
=======================

Comment: Yes, as pointed out by tripleee, your problem is quoting and you should use `echo "$params"`.

Comment: thanks Benjamin and triplee, it is great help, i dont know  how I missed this.
thanks :)